# Is there a way to generate a XML binding file from a class using MOXy?

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I'm would like to use MOXy to marshal / unmarshal object from existing classes.

I would like to know if there is a mean to generate XML binding files (cause I don't want to use annotations) from my classes.

Or do we have to do it all with our little hands :) ?

Answer (score 2):

By default JAXB/MOXy doesn't require any metadata to be specified (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).  You only need to specify the metadata where you want to override the default behaviour.

I'm guessing your real question is what is the easiest way to create the MOXy external mapping document.  I do the following with Eclipse, there are probably similar steps for your favourite IDE:

1. Get the XML Schema for MOXy's mapping document

   ```
   <EclipseLink_Home>/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_5.xsd
   ```
2. Register the XML Schema with your IDE

   1. Eclipse | Preferences | XML | XML Catalog | Add
3. Create and XML document in the IDE and specify the following as the root element.

   ```
   <xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"/>
   ```
4. Use the auto-complete functionality offered by your IDE to construct the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to generate jaxb classes and from those read the bindings (annotations) producing an external mapping (after which you can remove the annotations). PoC code:

```
    public class MoxyBindingGenerator {
    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.company.binding.jaxbclasses";
    private static ObjectFactory xmlBindingsFactory = new ObjectFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Collection<TypeInfo> typeInfos = readAnnotations();

        XmlBindings xmlBindings = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlBindings();
        xmlBindings.setPackageName(PACKAGE);

        JavaTypes javaTypes = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlBindingsJavaTypes();
        xmlBindings.setJavaTypes(javaTypes);
        List<JavaType> javaTypesList = javaTypes.getJavaType();

        XmlEnums xmlEnums = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlBindingsXmlEnums();
        xmlBindings.setXmlEnums(xmlEnums);
        List<XmlEnum> xmlEnumsList = xmlEnums.getXmlEnum();

        typeInfos.stream().forEach(typeInfo -> {
            if (!typeInfo.isEnumerationType()) {
                fillJavaTypes(javaTypesList, typeInfo);
            }
            else {
                fillEnumTypes(xmlEnumsList, typeInfo);
            }
        });

        saveToFile(xmlBindings);
    }

    private static Collection<TypeInfo> readAnnotations() throws JAXBException, Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = (JAXBContext) javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(PACKAGE);
        Object contextState = getPrivateField(jaxbContext, "contextState");
        Generator generator = (Generator) getPrivateField(contextState, "generator");
        AnnotationsProcessor annotationsProcessor = generator.getAnnotationsProcessor();
        Collection<TypeInfo> typeInfos = annotationsProcessor.getTypeInfo().values();
        return typeInfos;
    }

    private static void fillEnumTypes(List<XmlEnum> xmlEnumsList, TypeInfo typeInfo) {
        EnumTypeInfo et = (EnumTypeInfo) typeInfo;

        XmlEnum xmlEnum = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlEnum();
        xmlEnum.setJavaEnum(et.getJavaClassName());
        List<String> xmlEnumNames = et.getFieldNames();
        List<Object> xmlEnumValues = et.getXmlEnumValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlEnumNames.size(); i++) {
            String xmlEnumName = xmlEnumNames.get(i);
            Object xmlEnumObject = xmlEnumValues.get(i);

            XmlEnumValue xmlEnumValue = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlEnumValue();
            xmlEnumValue.setJavaEnumValue(xmlEnumName);
            xmlEnumValue.setValue(xmlEnumObject.toString());
            xmlEnum.getXmlEnumValue().add(xmlEnumValue);
        }
        xmlEnumsList.add(xmlEnum);
    }

    private static void fillJavaTypes(List<JavaType> javaTypesList, TypeInfo typeInfo) {
        JavaType javaType = xmlBindingsFactory.createJavaType();
        javaType.setName(typeInfo.getJavaClassName());
        fillXmlType(javaType, typeInfo);
        if (typeInfo.getXmlRootElement() != null) {
            XmlRootElement xmlRootElement = typeInfo.getXmlRootElement();
            xmlRootElement.setNamespace(null);
            javaType.setXmlRootElement(xmlRootElement);
        }
        JavaAttributes javaAttributes = xmlBindingsFactory.createJavaTypeJavaAttributes();
        javaType.setJavaAttributes(javaAttributes);
        List<JAXBElement<? extends JavaAttribute>> javaAttributeList = javaAttributes.getJavaAttribute();
        typeInfo.getNonTransientPropertiesInPropOrder().stream().forEach(field -> {
            fillFields(javaAttributeList, field);
        });
        javaTypesList.add(javaType);
    }

    private static void fillFields(List<JAXBElement<? extends JavaAttribute>> javaAttributeList, Property field) {
        if (field.getXmlElements() != null && field.getXmlElements().getXmlElement().size() > 0) {
            XmlElements xmlElements = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlElements();
            xmlElements.setJavaAttribute(field.getPropertyName());
            List<XmlElement> elements = field.getXmlElements().getXmlElement();
            elements.stream().forEach(e -> {
                e.setDefaultValue(null);
                e.setNamespace(null);
                xmlElements.getXmlElement().add(e);
            });
            JAXBElement<XmlElements> value = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlElements(xmlElements);
            javaAttributeList.add(value);
        }
        else if (!field.isAttribute()) {
            XmlElement value = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlElement();
            value.setJavaAttribute(field.getPropertyName());
            value.setName(field.getSchemaName().getLocalPart());
            if (field.isNillable())
                value.setNillable(field.isNillable());
            if (field.isRequired())
                value.setRequired(field.isRequired());
            javaAttributeList.add(xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlElement(value));
        }
        else {
            XmlAttribute value = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlAttribute();
            value.setJavaAttribute(field.getPropertyName());
            value.setName(field.getSchemaName().getLocalPart());
            javaAttributeList.add(xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlAttribute(value));
        }
    }

    private static void saveToFile(XmlBindings xmlBindings)
            throws JAXBException, PropertyException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        JAXBContext xmlModelJaxbContext =
            (JAXBContext) javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance("org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel");
        JAXBMarshaller marshaller = xmlModelJaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "binding-imspoor-oxm.xml"));
        marshaller.marshal(xmlBindings, fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    private static void fillXmlType(JavaType javaType, TypeInfo typeInfo) {
        XmlType orgXmlType = typeInfo.getXmlType();
        if (orgXmlType != null) {
            boolean add = false;
            XmlType xmlType = xmlBindingsFactory.createXmlType();
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(orgXmlType.getName())) {
                xmlType.setName(orgXmlType.getName());
                add = true;
            }
            if (orgXmlType.getPropOrder() != null && orgXmlType.getPropOrder().size() > 1) {
                xmlType.getPropOrder().addAll(orgXmlType.getPropOrder());
                add = true;
            }
            if (add)
                javaType.setXmlType(xmlType);
        }
    }

    private static Object getPrivateField(Object obj, String fieldName) throws Exception {
        Field declaredField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        return declaredField.get(obj);
    }
}
```